# Accurate body position detection

Tags: python, opencv, openpose

I'm new to opencv and I want to be able to detect a body position in the most accurate way. I don't care it won't be real-time.
I did a little research and came accrose `mediapipe` and `openpose`. They are both great but in some case don't provide an accurate result.

For an example, those are the results of `openpose`. You can see that body part 4 and 9 are not in the right position:
[image]

Again, I don't care about the time it will take to predict the results. Only care about accuracy.
One method I thought of doing is to use multiple position detection libraries and avarage the results. But I was wondering if there is a better way (or library) to do so.

Comment: That looks right to me (at least 4 and 9 are not particularly worse than all other numbers). What exactly do you think is the problem here?

Comment: @mkrieger1 4 and 9 (4 is more noticeable) are not excactly on the corrent position. 4 should be on the wrist, on the picture its on the air near the wrist.